# A user (super?)ping is showing up incorrectly in the chat star list

Tags: bug, chat

[This message by Rand al'Thor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36520105#36520105) is starred in Literature chat:

[image: Message reads: "@E.Bob Hello! This is the reading room ..."]

In the sidebar it looks like this:

[image: Message reads: "@@1208@literature.stackexchange.com Hello! This is the reading room ..."]

I imagine that should say `@E.Bob` not `@@1208@literature.stackexchange.com`. Turns out [I can ping people with that second format](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1208/e-bob) though!

I got curious about the significance of that "1208"; turns out [E.Bob is user #1208 on Literature SE](https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/1208/e-bob).

Answer (score 9):

Yeah, that's what happens when chat messages containing superpings get starred.

There's been a bug report about this on main meta, [Superpings don't show user name in sidebar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/248256/278659), which has been [status-ignored](/questions/tagged/status-ignored) for the last two years. I guess it's not a high-priority thing to fix. The double-ping syntax for superpings doesn't really need to be a big secret - there's no way for non-mods to abuse this information, since they can't use superpings anyway - so it's not a disastrous leak when it appears on the star-board. The only issue, then, is that it looks ugly, which ... well, meh.

Comment: The superping syntax [is officially public knowledge](https://stackmod.blog/category/newsletter/page/3/), so as you say there's no problem with it being revealed, and it could be seen on a message's history page anyway. But it's [weird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) that the star board (sidebar) can render (almost?) every other kind of inline formatting chat allows, but not `@@` pings. I noticed this with the short, numeric-only form of a superping recently, when a message containing chat-id superpings was starred in a chat room.